# Can you produce a wolf's template? Part 2

Tags: real, pencil-and-paper-games, paper-folding

Here is the first [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104068/can-you-fold-a-paper-make-one-hole-and-produce-a-bears-template).

You are given a square piece of paper with no marks on it. With this paper, you have to make a wolf's template.

[image]

You are given no tools such as a ruler or scissors, and all you can do is fold the paper and make an one hole with nail or hole puncher. You can produce the image anywhere on the paper. All holes should be connected with pencil. You can fold paper 6 or less times.

Can you fold the paper, make one hole, unfold it and obtain 8 holes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, within 4 folds, the Wolf imprint can be made.

Note for Fold 3:The top part of the Wolf's ear, goes back when we do the second fold, still try to match that dot (the paper comes from the back side)

Hope the diagram helps.
[image]

Comment: I don't think F3 is correct. At that point, the top dot is at the mirror image of F2, not at its original position. You can fix it by folding the mirror image onto the large dot instead.

Comment: How to find the F2 and F3 lines? Could you please clarify?

Comment: To clarify, the method I have used here is drawing the imprint and then trying to find symmetric lines between any two point to match them on top of each other. Regarding the F3 line, once the paper gets folded the top part of the ear gets brought to the downside, a reverse fold is needed there. That is the reason why the fold line is different.